onClick of rows of 'Master / Detail - Detail Grids' in ag-grid
onClick of rows of 'Master / Detail - Detail Grids' in ag-grid I want to perform some action, Is there any way to add onClick handler to ag-grid rows or cells?
I am using 30.2.1 version of ag-grid,
Also my application is react.js app
